# GridPane Column Index not working as expected (JavaFX)

Tags: java, css, javafx, gridpane

I have a problem getting the Column index working in JavaFX's GridPane.

I am setting up the grid in two phases. The first method distributes a few buttons in a 6x6 grid:

```
Button actualButton = new Button(ge.toString());
actualButton.getStyleClass().add("button");
rootNode.add(actualButton, gf.getX(), gf.getY());
```

where `gf.getX()` and `gf.getY()` are randomized numbers between 1 and 6 (making sure that no two buttons are put in the same cell.

This part works as expected. The problem is with the second part, when I want to put a Label below the `6x6` grid (ideally with a colspan of 6). No matter how I try, the Label will open a brand new column and push everything one column to the right. It is interesting, because I can set the row index, but not the column index. It also won't react to colspan.

This is the code I'm using, although I have tried various ways:

```
emptyFieldCounter = new Label("Number of empty fields: " + emptyFields.size());
rootNode.add(emptyFieldCounter,1,7,6,1);
```

I have tried to change the first int (that is supposedly the column index) to every possible value I could think of - nothing changes. If I change the second int, it will move to a different row, but remain in the same column.

here's a screenshot with 7 as the second int:
[image]

and one after changing the 2nd int after changing the col index and row index values to:

```
rootNode.add(emptyFieldCounter,3,3,6,1);
```

[image]

any hint would be very much appreciated.
cheers,
Zsolt

Comment: Btw, I know the value of empty slots is not correct, it's not a problem atm :-)

Comment: Can you create a [MCVE]? Your first version (`rootNode.add(emptyFieldCounter,1,7,6,1);`) works just fine in my quick test.

Comment: I guess... check that `gf.getX()` is giving you the values you think it is

Comment: Wow, when going for the minimal version, I drew up a quick 6x6 grid with this simple code:

`private void drawUp6by6Grid(){
        for (int i=0;i<6;i++)
        {
            Button button = new Button("i");
            rootNode.add(button,i,i);
        }
    }`

and following this method, the 

`rootNode.add(emptyFieldCounter,1,7,6,1);`

worked exactly as expected. So I may have to problem completely elsewhere, not where I was looking for it...

Will let you know once I find it,
thanks for the hint, anyway :-)

Comment: MCVEs are always useful for identifying where the problem is...

Comment: Thanks, @James_D - exactly as you suggested: gf.getX() wasn't giving a random value between 1-6, but a random value between A-F. 

but as char translates to int perfectly, the GridPane didn't complain

Thanks again for your quick help!